# Как отобрать все строки таблицы, язык R

Tags: r

Есть небольшой анализ кластерных данных, в результате которого я получаю кластера с данными. То есть игрок `[1]` относится к данным кластерам `5, 14, 20, 3` и т.д. А теперь я хочу получить выборку, которая покажет, какие игроки относятся к конкретному кластеру. То есть для этого надо отобрать все строки таблицы `Х`, у которых поле `X$Marks` равно 5. А как это сделать с помощью языка R?

```
> x<- read.table('d:\\2.csv', sep=';', header=TRUE)
> x <- x[-1] #отбросим колонку с именами игроков иначе ошибка при логарифмировании.
> x <- apply(x, 2, diff) #считаем разницу между последовательными элементами
> is.na(x) <- do.call(cbind,lapply(x, is.infinite)) # Заменить все Inf на NA
> is.na(x) <- do.call(cbind,lapply(x, is.nan)) # Заменить все NaN на NA
> x <- na.omit(x) # Удалить строки, содержащие NA
> clusters <- kmeans(x, 45, 1000000)
> x$Marks <- as.factor(clusters$cluster)
> print(x$Marks)
  [1] 5  14 20 3  37 33 34 29 33 23 11 6  23 11 21 32 21 24 16 21 24 29 27 38
 [25] 45 35 23 20 36 2  26 24 27 19 29 27 35 41 1  19 6  31 39 34 41 29 16 44
 [49] 12 16 44 29 27 23 24 16 37 20 3  6  20 18 2  8  32 30 14 36 3  6  3  37
 [73] 2  45 34 11 37 16 2  43 11 44 34 41 39 21 40 14 41 1  31 38 16 15 21 27
 [97] 2  11 21 23 41 12 43 16 29 1  19 36 37 25 21 44 15 20 37 41 21 5  4  8 
[121] 41 31 3  19 32 36 44 29 27 19 8  41 17 43 35 2  33 3  17 38 10 33 19 31
[145] 14 6  32 1  11 15 12 16 2  1  3  32 29 9  13 3  21 17 12 16 29 16 29 41
[169] 5  43 15 35 23 35 33 17 44 19 32 31 23 32 34 11 21 2  15 31 44 19 35 3 
[193] 20 44 11 23 32 11 12 16 36 3  6  17 29 17 1  6  21 41 34 35 41 1  11 19
[217] 3  11 17 11 3  2  5  4  1  37 14 33 12 4  23 30 14 8  27 8  43 19 14 32
[241] 5  4  11 36 8  27 35 36 11 23 11 24 16 32 43 11 19 32 43 36 34 41 35 32
[265] 29 4  33 31 30 11 31 30 25 23 6  29 16 31 21 29 17 11 23 36 24 37 16 24
[289] 15 39 20 12 4  16 8  41 36 19 31 32 43 36 11 39 12 43 27 35 8  35 5  16
[313] 44 8  36 23 38 16 28 20 8  23 29 16 32 38 45 2  39 24 19 39 7  11 8  35
[337] 9  13 6  43 27 8  31 18 41 29 10 12 1  8  36 20 3  36 27 35 21 40 42 18
[361] 29 27 26 39 20 24 3  26 24 43 23 26 24 15 20 23 38 16 29 19 17 43 36 4 
[385] 43 17 18 29 4  31 19 43 1  32 39 36 19 20 24 20 27 29 4  40 42 20 12 16
[409] 8  35 33 32 11 36 37 21 12 4  29 10 8  32 3  31 12 4  23 11 8  36 17 11
[433] 19 1  37 11 25 32 3  36 29 35 9  13 11 27 8  36 41 15 24 35 20 15 12 4 
[457] 14 6  31 23 40 42 24 26 8  3  36 24 43 1  8  41 28 22 36 31 29 27 39 19
[481] 20 6  31 8  31 7  13 23 19 3  24 17 21 5  16 1  24 21 11 16 8  36 28 22
[505] 31 6  33 8  24 16 24 28 32 27 29 21 41 15 24 31 21 12 4  8  7  13 27 44
[529] 34 23 32 32 1  44 37 8  16 38 45 2  38 10
45 Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 ... 45
```

Comment: Посмотрите справку к функции `merge`.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> отобрать все строки таблицы Х, у которых поле X$Marks равно 5

например, с помощью [функции `subset`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/subset).

---

#### пример:

имеется таблица `m`:

```
> m
  x y marks
1 0 1     2
2 3 4     5
3 6 7     8
4 9 0     5
```

полученная так:

```
> as.table(matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,5),ncol=3,byrow=T)) -> m
> c('x','y','marks') -> names(m)
```

отобрать строки, в которых `marks` равно `5`, можно, например, так:

```
> subset(m,marks==5)
  x y marks
2 3 4     5
4 9 0     5
```